# How do i display non-validation errors in jsp with spring webflow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

How do i display non-validation errors in jsp with spring webflow.

Something equivalent to struts ActionErrors/

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Spring Web Flow uses Spring MVC in the background. But adding messages manually to the MessageContext object which sits inside the RequestContext, we can display error messages on the screen. It's the same place where even the validation errors messages are stored.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is following:

```
<c:forEach items='<%=((RequestContext) jspContext.findAttribute("flowRequestContext")).getMessageContext().getMessagesBySource(null)%>' var="msg">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${msg.severity.label eq 'Error'}">
            ERROR: ${msg.text}
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            ERROR: ${msg.text}
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

And messages are added this way (eg. in controllers):

```
context.getMessageContext().addMessage(new MessageBuilder().error().code("localized.error.code").build());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<c:forEach items="${flowRequestContext.messageContext.allMessages}"     var="message">
  <li>
    Message Source is ${message.source}
    <br>
    Message Text is ${message.text}
  </li>
</c:forEach>
```

credit to this [how do i show error/info/fatal messages in jsp when i using spring-webflow with POJO action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648882/how-do-i-show-error-info-fatal-messages-in-jsp-when-i-using-spring-webflow-with)