# how do i show error/info/fatal messages in jsp when i using spring-webflow with POJO action?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-webflow

i am using spring-mvc(3.2.4) and spring-webflow(2.3.2) here.
i define a flow like this:

```
<flow>
<decision-state id="check">
    <if test="signupFlowAction.checkPrecondition(messageContext)" then="firstState" else="error" />
</decision-state>

<view-state id="firstState">
    ... 
</view-state>

<view-state id="error" view="error/bad-thing-happens">
    ...
</view-state>
```

i want to check some business preconditions when the flow startup, so i using a POJO to do so.

```
public boolean checkPrecondition(MessageContext messageContext) {

    boolean oh_snap = true;

    if (oh_snap) {
        MessageResolver mr1 = new MessageBuilder().fatal().defaultText("fatal message here.").build();
        MessageResolver mr2 = new MessageBuilder().error().defaultText("error message here.").build();
        MessageResolver mr3 = new MessageBuilder().info().defaultText("info message here.").build();

        messageContext.addMessage(mr1);
        messageContext.addMessage(mr2);
        messageContext.addMessage(mr3);
    }

    return ! oh_snap;
}
```

this code is fine, but i do not kown how to show the messages in jsp. 
spring's taglibs did't work? i tried `<spring:error path="*"/>` nothing happened.

Answer (score 4):

In your `JSP` file, try something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${flowRequestContext.messageContext.allMessages}" var="message">
  <li>
    Message Source is ${message.source}
    <br>
    Message Text is ${message.text}
  </li>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've got the Spring Form taglib directive specified as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Then I think the correct syntax to use the errors tag is:

```
<form:errors path="*" />
```